# How to call "User ID" variable from localStorage to PHP using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, database

So, i want to select "Notes" based on "userID". Here's what I did

use angular.js to call the PHP function

```
$scope.dapatkanData = function(){
    $http.get(
        '../php/displayNotes.php'
    ).success(function(data){
        $scope.notes = data;
    });
};
```

create displayNotes.php to select data from the database where localStorage.getItem("ID")

```
<?php

    include('connect.php');

    $postdata = file_get_contents(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    $dataObjek = json_decode($postdata);

    $user = $dataObjek->userID;
    $hashtype = "sha256";

    $userID = hash($hashType,$user);

    $perintah_sql = "select * from notes where notesID='{$userID}'";

    $data = [];

    $result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$perintah_sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $temp_data = [];
        $temp_data['notesID'] = $row['notesID'];
        $temp_data['notesNo'] = $row['notesNo'];
        $temp_data['notesTitle'] = $row['notesTitle'];
        $temp_data['notesContent'] = $row['notesContent'];
        $temp_data['notesDate'] = $row['notesDate'];

        array_push($data,$temp_data);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

but then it returns nothing after i loaded the app, i don't know what should i do now... been searching for hours but still no solution

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is client side storage only. nither you or I or any server can't access what is stored on a clients browser storage.

You either need to set the value as cookie so it gets sent to the server in every request or pass along the localStorage value with your http request

You probably want to send a query parameter

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'displayNotes.php',
 data: { userID: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Then in your **displayNotes.php** You would have to change it to this

```
$postdata = file_get_contents($_GET['userID']);
```

I would also do a litle more security checks on this one since it can be changed to 
`?userID=../db-config.json` or something similar. You allow clients to read a almost any file they want you to

Comment: any idea how to do that?

Comment: i've also tried to use the localStorage inside the javascript but still no result....

Comment: Have you stored **user** somewhere?

Comment: i stored the user in the db (hashed) and using localStorage.setItem as a plaintext

Comment: I'm still quite a newbie so i might not understand what you're saying, sorry if i asked something just like what a newbie asked

Comment: and do security checks like that necessary when you're deploying this on phonegap? just wondering since i can't input address myself